# Updating server to 12.04 on release

Tags: server, updates, 12.04, release-management

I'm currently running a lamp server using Ubuntu 11.10. With the release of 12.04 this week I'm wondering whether I should update to 12.04 right away or if I should wait some time.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can safely update directly, I updated my LAMP server to an RC and no problems appeared.